# Add list of numbers to an empty list using for loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Faced a wall recently with somewhat simple thing but no matter what I am unable to solve it.
I created a small function that calculates some values and returns a list as an output value

```
def calc(file):
    #some calculation based on file
    return degradation #as a list
```

for example, for file "data1.txt"

```
degradation = [1,0.9,0.8,0.5]
```

and for file "data2.txt"

```
degradation = [1,0.8,0.6,0.2]
```

Since I have several files on which I want to apply the calc() I wanted them to connect them, sideways, so that I connect them into an array which has `len(degradation)` number of rows, and columns as much as I have files. Was planning to do it with `for` loop.

For this specific case something like:

```
output = 1 , 1
         0.9,0.8
         0.8,0.6
         0.5,0.2
```

Tried with pandas as well but without a success.

Comment: It seems as if a numpy matrix is what you are looking for. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

arr2d = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
arr2d = np.append(arr2d, [[9, 8, 7, 6]], axis=0).T
```

expect an output something like this:

```
array([[1, 9],
       [2, 8],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.hstack()` to achieve this.
Imagine you have data from the first two files from the first two iterations of the for loop.
data1.txt gives you

```
degradation1 = [1,0.9,0.8,0.5]
```

and data2.txt gives you

```
degradation2 = [1,0.8,0.6,0.2]
```

First, you have to convert both lists into lists of lists.

```
degradation1 = [[i] for i in degradation1]
degradation2 = [[i] for i in degradation2]
```

This gives the outputs,

```
print(degradation1)
print(degradation2)

[[1], [0.9], [0.8], [0.5]]
[[1], [0.8], [0.6], [0.2]]
```

Now you can stack the data using the `numpy.hstack()`.

```
stacked = numpy.hstack(degradation1,degradation2)
```

This gives the output

```
array([[1. , 1. ],
       [0.9, 0.8],
       [0.8, 0.6],
       [0.5, 0.2]])
```

Imagine you have the file data3.text during the 3rd iteration of the for loop and it gives

```
degradation3 = [1,0.3,0.6,0.4]
```

You can follow the same steps as above and stack it with `stacked`. Follow the steps; convert to a list of the lists, stack with `stacked`.

```
degradation3 = [[i] for i in degradation3]
stacked = numpy.hstack(stacked,degradation3)
```

This gives you the output

```
array([[1. , 1. , 1. ],
       [0.9, 0.8, 0.3],
       [0.8, 0.6, 0.6],
       [0.5, 0.2, 0.4]])
```

You can continue this for the whole loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assume `my_lists` is a list of your lists.

```py
my_lists = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [10, 20, 30, 40],
    [100, 200, 300, 400]]

result = []

for _ in my_lists[0]:
    result.append([])

for l in my_lists:
    for i in range(len(result)):
        result[i].append(l[i])

for line in result:
    print(line)
```

The output would be

```
[1, 10, 100]
[2, 20, 200]
[3, 30, 300]
[4, 40, 400]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to want to work with lists

```
## degradations as list
degradation1 = [1,0.8,0.6,0.2]
degradation2 = [1,0.9,0.8,0.5]
degradation3 = [0.7,0.9,0.8,0.5]

degradations = [degradation1, degradation2, degradation3]

## CORE OF THE ANSWER ##
degradationstransposed = [list(i) for i in zip(*degradations)]

print(degradationstransposed)
[[1, 1, 0.7], [0.8, 0.9, 0.9], [0.6, 0.8, 0.8], [0.2, 0.5, 0.5]]
```